# Parse controls in an aspx file using RegEx

Tags: c#, xml, regex

given an aspx file, I want to parse its controls. I saw other posts on the same topics, but it doesn't really fit my needs.

Example:

```
<Ctl:Label id="MyLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True">Text of My label</Ctl:Label>
```

I want to retrieve these informations (the form does not matter, provided that the information are separated):

```
Tag = "Ctl"
Type = "Label"
id = "MyLabel"
runat = "server"
Font-Bold = "True"
Content = "Text of My label"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972167/parse-controls-in-an-aspx-file-and-convert-it-to-xml) is close to what I want, but it does not allow me to retrieve "Text of My label" for example.

Note: I don't need to put this information in a xml file, but why not.

Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I need to parse a lot of aspx pages with a desktop program written in C#, not with asp.net.

**EDIT 2: Why?** Because I have a lot of asp.net pages, that contain server controls that I maintain. I need to retrieve information about in which pages I can find these controls, and most information about them (name, id, what inner controls they eventually have, etc., to say only that), but just focus on the main question, then I will handle the rest.

Comment: Perhaps if you mention _why_ you're trying to do this someone will be able to better help you. ASP already parses its own controls; it has an entire assembly dedicated to that, and the runtime has methods that allow you to load and parse controls independently of the page cycle.

Comment: Just aspx files on a local filesystem

Comment: Um... there is probably no non-sarcastic way to say this, but isn't this what the IDE itself is for? You want to know every a certain control appears?  Ctrl + F. Done.

Comment: @GrayFox374 There are hundreds of those aspx files...Plus, they are not in the same application. Therefore, Ctrl + F will not do the job. Furthermore, where would be the gain of productivity when I want to just retrieve information about the controls, if the whole code appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to parse the files using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and then locate the controls by element name.

Comment: I don't see "aspx" mentioned anywhere, but I will give it a try tomorrow, thanks

Comment: That is the best choice for me, and will save me a lot of time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to achieve automation; to me, that suggests looking for the most reliable solution, otherwise the automation isn't worth much because you will have to assume that any part of it might have failed.

There are a few ways I can think of to approach this:

**1 - Regex**
A regex will work fine as long as you aren't trying to turn the whole thing into a perfectly-structured result. While a typical ASCX is a little more structured than plain HTML (or else it won't run), it still has the potential to be malformed. As such, it suffers from the usual HTML parsing foibles.

**2 - Parser**
A simple state machine parser could help you identify specific controls and account for scenarios which a regex can't handle. This could be as simple or as elaborate as you wanted to make it. An advanced parser could build an entire hierarchy; a simple parser might just retrieve all the controls and perhaps inline code blocks (<%= %>) and data binding information.

**3 - Use the compiled assemblies**
As you probably know, an ASP.Net application is converted from markup into c# classes, and then to assemblies. These assemblies are available in the `%System%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` directory. While they aren't well-named (since they aren't intended for direct consumption) they *do* contain an extremely accurate representation of how .Net views the page/control. You could use reflection to access this data.

The contents of one of these files contains data such as this declaration of a `ValidationSummary`:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary @__BuildControlvs() {
    global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary @__ctrl;

    #line 6 "C:\Development\VS 2010\..."
    @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary();

    #line default
    #line hidden
    this.vs = @__ctrl;
    @__ctrl.TemplateControl = this;
    @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this.Page);

    #line 6 "C:\Development\VS 2010\..."
    @__ctrl.ID = "vs";

    #line default
    #line hidden

    #line 6 "C:\Development\VS 2010\..."
    @__ctrl.ValidationGroup = "Group1";

    return @__ctrl;
}
```

As you can see, these classes contain complete data for the page or control. They also contain line numbers and file names to the original code (might be useful to you).

### Summary

Option #1 is the quickest for simple scenarios. Option #3 is very powerful but tightly coupled to the application's physical infrastructure and somewhat coupled to how the autogenerated code is structured. Option #2 will require the most work.

Lastly, there may be a way to programmatically access the markup-to-c# converter and compile the assemblies yourself (as is done when an application is first accessed - similar to option #3).

Comment: +1, Thanks for such a complete answer. I didn't know about option 3, but it won't be possible, as I can't access the compiled assemblies. I did start to write a parser and meanwhile I found the regex solution that was so quick, but not complete enough, so I was trying to upgrade it